# how to correctly import data from *.csv file to a given table in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have a .csv file with rows like this:

16.11.2015 00:00:01.118,0.94674,0.94641,1000000.0000,1750000.0000

now i'd need to import the values to mysql database to a table with 9 cols so:

col1 - 16.11.2015
col2 - 00
col3 - 00
col4 - 01
col5 - 118
col6 - 0.94674
col7 - 0.94641
col8 - 1000000.0000
col9 - 1750000.0000

has anyone an idea how to separate the values f.e. with standard command like :
load data infile 'file.csv' into table nameoftable fields terminated by ',';

i tried to look for something on mysql knowledge base but no resuld, which would be work...thanks

Comment: why break up the date\time and not store it as one?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
 $file_handle = fopen($file, "r"); //opens CSV
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ",")) !== false){
           ...code..
    }
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: i'd like to a direct mysql command if it is possible? i'd like to load the csv file directly to the DB with LOAD command.

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to a direct mysql command if it is possible? i'd like to load the csv file directly to the DB with LOAD command.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html?

Also, some database manager/tools have the ability to import CSV files. I'm using Sequel Pro and it has the ability to do so.

Comment: but i need a command, which will be a part of my own app then. maybe it's not possible to do it with 1-step coomand...??